# GET запрос через PHP внутри SuiteCRM

Tags: php, get, suitecrm

Я написал view.php который принимал ajax запросы и работал с БД но в итоге появились рад проблем из за которых пришлось отказаться от ajax и посылать запрос через php.
file_get_contents() как и include не работают толи шуга блочит толи еще что...

Есть-ли аналог ajax в php??

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, кто такая шуга ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php

Comment: @zalex SuiteCRM - это форк SugarCRM